# Separating neutral and ground in panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, grounding-and-bonding

I have a 200 amp combination disconnect and 10 circuit panel on the pole feeding my 200 amp panel in my house. Is the panel on my pole considered my main panel and the one in my house a sub-panel requiring me to seperate my ground and neutral? I have run 4-wire underground to my home and was planning on separating the ground and neutral. What do you think? Would love some feedback. Thanks

Comment: Is the neutral bonded to ground in the panel on the pole?  Is there a grounding electrode system at the pole?

Answer (score 2):

The first means of disconnect is considered the service. In your case the one on the pole.

Any panels fed from that would be considered sub-panels and should keep the grounds and neutrals separate and leave the bonding screw out.

The conductors between the service and sub-panel are considered feeders even if they are protected by an overcurrent device and should be run accordingly.

Good luck and stay safe!